# A formula to lookup a value in another column error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Dears
Greetings

I need a formula to search for value in a column If it matches. The return value should be W

I tried Xlookup

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$6,$C$2,0,0)
```

[image]

Final result should be as photo below

[image]

***W is just an indicator that means there is a match***

Comment: It is returning error which is correct since, it is two arguments in `XLOOKUP()`. Make sure that **both ranges** are the **same size**. `=XLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$6,$C$2,0,0)` will return a `#VALUE!` Error because the `Lookup_Array` is 6 rows and the `Return_Array` is only 1 row. Also please explain the logic to return the `W` for other numbers.

Comment: W is just an indicator that means there is a match

Comment: So you need either `MATCH()` or `XMATCH()` function and with `XLOOKUP()` also i have posted in `Answer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using <kbd>XMATCH( )</kbd> & <kbd>ISNUMBER( )</kbd> instead of <kbd>XLOOKUP( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$8)),"W","")
```

---

Or,

You can also use <kbd>XLOOKUP( )</kbd> in this way

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=IF(ISNA(XLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$8,$B$2:$B$8)),"","W")
```

---